# why calling a function within object markup is valid?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Can someone please explain to me how this is valid? I never seen anything like it nor I expected it to be valid.

https://gist.github.com/martinaglv/0cf3f564d9c31c053da5#file-13-js

```js
function whatDoesItDo(){

    var values = [];
    
    myBlock: {
        values.push('1');
        values.push('2');
        break myBlock;
        values.push('3');
    }
    
    values.push('4');
    
    return values.join(',');
}
```

Comment: `myBlock:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) rather than a property key and the braces define a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) rather than an Object.

Comment: Didn't know that is possible... is it a good practice to use it? I've never come across it except when its like in switch statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funny enough, this thing (myBlock) is a code label, a very old tool used to give names to code blocks. this is widely used while coding, like, assembly when using jump instructions and such. it is also the used in order to use functions like 'goto' (don't it's evil!!).

so, in here this is just a block called "myBlock" that inserts elements into the array. the break means that this is where the code will stop executing in the block (that's why only 2 elements in the array there).

later, after '4' is also inserted, the join method turns the array into a string made from the array's elements, joined by a "," delimiter.
(so it becomes like "1,2,4") and that's the return value

Comment: When you say "give name to code blocks" is that a good thing to do? I've never ever come across it anywhere and I can't any practical real world example... This is one of those obscure old school features in Js?

Comment: usually you won't see anyone doing such a thing. it might be useful in cases like, you've got some loop inside a loop and you'd want on some condition, break not only the other loop but also the other loop. then you can define the outer loop as a codeblock, say "myblock" and then break myblock. since there are many other ways to do this, and it makes your code look unclean you won't use it. anyhow, the option exists.